# Drawing a lot lines between surfaces in Famo.us?

Tags: canvas, svg, famo.us

My goal is to be able to render a graph database (nodes connected by lines) in a way that looks really good and animates smoothly when new nodes are added. I have been looking at SVG, Canvas, and now Famo.us.

Famo.us seems like it might be good for this because I could use Famo.us Surfaces to render each node including HTML-formatted text and controls. The problem is drawing the lines to connect the nodes. Famo.us doesn't have primitives like lines. It does have canvas surfaces, but that doesn't seem like the right approach.

I'm guessing I'd have to do something quite awkward for each line like create a tall, thin surface and calculate a transform that would make it connect between two surfaces.

Comment: Did you make any progress? I am asking myself the same question.

Comment: I gave up on Famo.us and decided canvas and svg are better options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example of 2 draggable surfaces with a line between them. The line is created with another surface.

Running demo http://gazibit.com/widget/31

```
var Engine = famous.core.Engine;
var Surface = famous.core.Surface;
var Modifier = famous.core.Modifier;
var Transform = famous.core.Transform;
var Draggable = famous.modifiers.Draggable;
var StateModifier = famous.modifiers.StateModifier;

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();


var lineOptions = {thickness:2,
                 lineColor:'#FA5C4F'};

//line surface
var ls = new Surface({
    origin:[0,.5],
    properties:{
      backgroundColor:lineOptions.lineColor
    }
});
initLine();
//Add the 2 blocks that will be joined by the line
ls.s1 = createBlock("s1",[100,100]);
ls.s2 = createBlock("s2",[300,100]);


//----------------------
//  HELPER FUNCTIONS
//----------------------
function initLine(){
var canvasModifier = new Modifier({
    size:function(){
      var len = _getLineLength()+5;
      return [len,lineOptions.thickness];
    },
    transform: function() {
        var p = _getPosition();
        return Transform.translate(p[0], p[1], 0);
    }
  });

var rotateModifier = new Modifier({
  transform: function (){
    var _s = _getRect();
    var angle  = Math.atan2(_s[1],_s[0]);
    return Transform.rotateZ(angle);
  } 
});

mainContext.add(canvasModifier).add(rotateModifier).add(ls);  
}

function createBlock(cnt,initialPosition){
var s = new Surface(
{ size:[100,100],
  content:cnt,
  properties:{
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FA5C4F'
  }
});
//Save the current position of the new surface
s.currentPosition = initialPosition;
var draggable = new Draggable();
draggable.obj = s;
s.pipe(draggable);
mainContext.add(draggable).add(s);
draggable.setPosition(initialPosition);
draggable.on('update',function(e){
  this.obj.currentPosition = e.position;   
});
return s;
}

//gets the position of where the line should start
function _getPosition(){
var dta = _getObjects();
var pnts = _getEndPoints(dta);
return pnts[0];
}

//Gets the Dx and Dy of line to calculate hypotenous
function _getRect(){
var res = [0,0];
var dta = _getObjects();
var pnts = _getEndPoints(dta);
var p1 = pnts[0];
var p2 = pnts[1];
res[0] = p2[0]-p1[0];
res[1] = p2[1]-p1[1];
return res;
}
function _getLineLength(){
var res = _getRect();
return Math.sqrt( ((res[0] * res[0]) + (res[1] * res[1])) );
}


function _getEndPoints(dta){
var dx = dta.rm.currentPosition[0]-dta.lmredge;
var dy = dta.bm.currentPosition[1]-dta.tmbedge;
if ( (dx <= 0) && (dy <= 0) ) {
  //objects are overlapping. Draw no line
  return [[0,0],[0,0]];
}
else if (dx > dy){
  //draw line from R and L edges
  var lmYMidPoint = dta.lm.currentPosition[1]+(dta.lm.size[1]/2);
  var rmYMidPoint = dta.rm.currentPosition[1]+(dta.rm.size[1]/2);
  var p1 = [dta.lmredge,lmYMidPoint];
  var p2 = [dta.rm.currentPosition[0],rmYMidPoint];
  return [p1,p2];
}
else {
  //draw line from B and Top edges
  var tmXMidPoint = dta.tm.currentPosition[0]+(dta.tm.size[0]/2);
  var bmXMidPoint = dta.bm.currentPosition[0]+(dta.bm.size[0]/2);
  var p1 = [tmXMidPoint,dta.tmbedge];
  var p2 = [bmXMidPoint,dta.bm.currentPosition[1]];
  return [p1,p2];
}
}

//Mark the objects as 
//top most, left most, bottom most, right most
function _getObjects(){
var lm = _getLeftMost(ls);
var rm = ls.s1;
if (lm == rm){
  rm = ls.s2;
}
var tm = _getTopMost(ls);
var bm = ls.s1;
if (tm == bm){
  bm = ls.s2;
}

var lm_redge = (lm.currentPosition[0]+lm.size[0]);
var lm_bedge = (lm.currentPosition[1]+lm.size[1]);
var rm_redge = (rm.currentPosition[0]+rm.size[0]);
var rm_bedge = (rm.currentPosition[1]+rm.size[1]);

var tm_redge = (tm.currentPosition[0]+tm.size[0]);
var tm_bedge = (tm.currentPosition[1]+tm.size[1]);
var bm_redge = (bm.currentPosition[0]+bm.size[0]);
var bm_bedge = (bm.currentPosition[1]+bm.size[1]);


return {lm:lm,rm:rm,tm:tm,bm:bm,
        lmredge:lm_redge,
        lmbedge:lm_bedge,
        rmredge:rm_redge,
        rmbedge:rm_bedge,
        tmredge:tm_redge,
        tmbedge:tm_bedge,
        bmredge:bm_redge,
        bmbedge:bm_bedge};
}

function _getLeftMost(obj){
if (obj.s1.currentPosition[0] <= obj.s2.currentPosition[0]){
  return obj.s1;
} else {
  return obj.s2;
}
}

function _getTopMost(obj){
if (obj.s1.currentPosition[1] <= obj.s2.currentPosition[1]){
  return obj.s1;
} else {
  return obj.s2;
}
}
```

Comment: That works great. They should incorporate that into Famo.us as a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tried anything like this myself. I have seen some in-development stuff involving a famo.us inspector. Which is basically a chrome extension that draws the heirarchy of a famo.us scene.

If you perhaps analyze the code, and install the extension yourself to see it in action, you may find a route to achieving the result's you're looking for. If I recall, the hierarchy is drawn as a family tree style illustration, which allows for dynamic addition and removal of nodes, connected by fluid lines.

Of course, it's in development, and probably a rickety prototype, so don't expect any support or feedback.

https://github.com/FamousInternal/famous-inspector

Comment: The repository is not public anymore (or deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use a surface with one narrow dimension and a rotate transform?

```
var lineSurface = new Surface({
  size: [150,1],
  properties: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});

var rotateModifier = new StateModifier({
  transform: Transform.rotateZ(Math.PI/4)
});

mainContext.add(rotateModifier1).add(lineSurface);
```